# Where can I find the list of options for the apt-key adv command?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt

The manual page of the `apt-key` command has this:

```
  adv
           Pass advanced options to gpg. With adv --recv-key you can e.g.
           download key from keyservers directly into the trusted set of keys.
```

With some searching I found the `--fetch-keys` and `--keyserver` options but no description of what they are and no list of their friends if there are any.

If I missed the right documentation I'd be happy to be shown where to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `man gpg`. For example you find there:

> --fetch-keys URIs
>
> Retrieve keys located at the specified URIs. Note that different installations of GnuPG may support different protocols (HTTP, FTP, LDAP, etc.).  When using HTTPS the system provided root certificates are used by this command.

Or

> --keyserver name
>
> This option is deprecated - please use the --keyserver in `dirmngr.conf' instead.
> [...]